# Hapi FHIR - Appointment with patientId and list of service category name

Tags: java, hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I am new to HAPI FHIR api,
But I am trying to get Appointment resources for a patientID with service category and service type code.

I can find appointments for patient with `withIDAndCompartment` but not sure how to add the search criteria.

```
Bundle bundle = fhirClient.search().forResource(Patient.class).withIdAndCompartment(patientId, ResourceType.Appointment.name()).returnBundle(Bunle.class).execute();

List<Appointment> appointments = BundleUtil.toListOfResourcesOfType(fhirClient.getFhirContext(), bundle, Appointment.class);
```

will return patientId's appointments.

I am not sure how to use TokenClientParam, `Appointment.SERVICE_CATEGORY` or `Appointment.SERVICE_TYPE`, to search the appointment type with the input service category or service type code.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields you want to search have all been added to the `Search parameter` by `HAPI FHIR`, you can refer to my code below

```
    public List<Appointment> findByPatientIdAndServiceTypeAndServiceCategory(
            final String patientId,
            final String serviceType,
            final String serviceCategory,
            final int offset,
            final int limit,
            final Collection<Include> includes) {
        final IQuery<?> theQuery = fhirClient.search().forResource(Appointment.class)
            .totalMode(SearchTotalModeEnum.ACCURATE)
            .offset(offset)
            .count(limit);

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(patientId)) {
            theQuery.and(Appointment.PATIENT.hasId(patientId));
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(serviceType)) {
            theQuery.and(Appointment.SERVICE_TYPE.exactly().code(serviceType));
        }

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(serviceCategory)) {
            theQuery.and(Appointment.SERVICE_CATEGORY.exactly().code(serviceCategory));
        }

        CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(includes).forEach(theQuery::include);

        theQuery.returnBundle(Bundle.class).execute();
        Bundle result = theQuery.returnBundle(Bundle.class).execute();

        if (result.getEntry().isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        return result.getEntry()
            .stream()
            .filter(entryComponent -> entryComponent.getResource() instanceof Appointment)
            .map(entry -> (Appointment) entry.getResource())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
// Create the search parameters
AppointmentSearchParams searchParams = new AppointmentSearchParams();
searchParams
  .setServiceCategory(new TokenClientParam("http://example.com/fhir/service-category", "category-code"))
  .setServiceType(new TokenClientParam("http://example.com/fhir/service-type", "type-code"));

// Execute the search
Bundle bundle = fhirClient.search()
  .forResource(Appointment.class)
  .withIdAndCompartment(patientId, ResourceType.Patient.name())
  .where(searchParams)
  .returnBundle(Bundle.class)
  .execute();

// Retrieve the Appointments from the search results
List<Appointment> appointments = BundleUtil.toListOfResourcesOfType(fhirClient.getFhirContext(), bundle, Appointment.class);
```

NB: you should replace http://example.com/fhir/service-category and http://example.com/fhir/service-type with the actual system values for the service category and service type codes you want to search for. If you don't know these or want to search for across all systems then your search params will need to look like below. Notice the use of null instead of the actual system value:

```
// Create the search parameters
AppointmentSearchParams searchParams = new AppointmentSearchParams();
searchParams
  .setServiceCategory(new TokenClientParam(null, "category-code"))
  .setServiceType(new TokenClientParam(null, "type-code"));
```

Comment: I actually have tried this myself. Just that the server doesn't have the endpoint Appointment/<APPOINTMENT_ID>/Patient and throws error,
The FHIR endpoint on this server does not know how to handle GET operation[Appointment/<APPOINTENT_ID>/Patient]

Comment: That would be the correct behavior according to the FHIR specification for the Appointment resource, see https://www.hl7.org/fhir/appointment.html, perhaps @fixcer is onto something you should maybe try?